# How to align the joints of a manipulator with high accuracy on ROS

Tags: ros, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like to know how we can align the joints of a robotic arm. Currently we can only do trial and error for correcting the origins of joints .Its a very time consuming task and cant use for complex robotic system. If ROS has a plugin or package to export the 3D models designed in popular softwares such as SolidWorks,Autocad,Blender,FreeCAD, it will be great tool for robotic model designers. Is any package existing for converting this 3D models into URDF or xacro? And which is the best tool for modelling Robots  in  Opensource community?  I think ROS developers have to give more importance to modelling tools.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37588/how-to-align-the-joints-of-a-manipulator-with-high-accuracy-on-ros/) by [Lentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2749/lentin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tool was developed to convert CAD models to URDF models semi-automatically. It makes use of the XML files exported by the SimMechanics Link . Mathworks, makers of SimMechanics, have developed plugins for a couple of leading CAD programs, including SolidWorks, ProEngineer and Inventor.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/simmechanics_to_urdf

http://www.ros.org/wiki/simmechanics_to_urdf/Tutorials/Converting%20SimMechanics%20To%20URDF

hope this give you a hint

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0